# Bad Gateway in an express and react app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk despite a successful build

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an express app with react as a front end framework on Elastic Beanstalk. The build succeeds however the website always returns with a Bad Gateway 502. I am trying to build the react app on **eb** and start the node.js server after react builds successfully, using a `deploy` script defined in `package.json` and a `Procfile`.

**Package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "ecosys",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "history": "5",
    "i18next": "^21.6.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-query": "^3.32.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.1",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run start",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: npm run deploy
```

I think that the react build succeeds but it never launches the node.js server, It never runs `npm run start`.

Comment: Did you look at the application logs? What did you find?

Comment: The react-script build succeeded, but still a bad gateway

Comment: Currently, I am building my react app locally and sending the build files to be served statically with the express server. Cons of this approach that the react app requires some env variables (staging, production) that must be read from eb